# JS date giving wrong month

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been working with dates in node for a while now. I had an issue where the date was giving the wrong date after adding months. I ran some tests.

```
const d = new Date('2021-05-01');
console.log(d); // 2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(d); // 2021-05-31T00:00:00.000Z
```

I was confused why this wasn't just giving me **2021-06-01**
after running

```
console.log(d.getMonth())
```

I realized it was returning 3 which is not May

Then I ran

```
console.log(d.toDateString())
```

Which gave me **Fri Apr 30 2021**

So my question is why does it make **new Date('2021-05-01')** actually April 30th?

Comment: I think there must be some other code that's missing here? I can't reproduce your problem. What else are you doing / using that may affect dates in some way?

Comment: Nothing else in my code. I am running all that in a separate instance to my actual program and can reproduce on both

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it in a codepen that you can link to?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Hant0010/pen/dyVVOag

Comment: That's strange, it outputs correctly for me ("Sat May 01 2021 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")

Comment: ah okay well that answers it. Its a timezone thing. for me it outputs Fri Apr 30 2021 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) but if I add a time 00:00:00 to the date it turns it to May

Comment: Didn't expect it to work like that, but that must be it. It must be based off GMT and add or subtracts hours based on the local machine's time zone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240359/discussion-between-cameron-hanton-and-joseph).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out that its because of timezones. I should of guess that, but if anyone else is in need of a fix you can simple add the time to the date to bring it to the actual date.

```
const date = new Date('2021-05-01 00:00:00');
```

Comment: '2021-05-01 00:00:00' is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari at least treats it as an invalid date. Replacing the central space with the letter "T" fixes that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have `node.js v17.3.0` and cannot recreate your problem (unfortunately I can't comment yet).

So my suggestion would be to check your node installation or perhaps reinstall node.
After running your code in node REPL, I get `Tue Jun 01 2021` as result. I live in Germany, I don't know if that helps.